# The requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system

Tags: php, composer-php

So I just installed Scotchbox (a vagrant setup).
https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box

I'm trying to install a composer dependancy when I get the following error.

```
Problem 1
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage (locked at 4.0.8) -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[4.0.8].
```

### What I've tried

Some other thread suggested that this is included in the php-xml package. I tried installing this doing

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But that didn't work. 
Any idea what other solutions might work? I'm starting to pull my hair out.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

For me the selected answer didn't work.

This did work:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

This was on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.

Comment: This answer still works as of PHP 8.2.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-common
```

Answer (score 12):

use `sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml` if you are using ubuntu and php-fpm7.2

Answer (score 11):

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and PHP 7.1 is running well using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

and then (if using apache)

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or if on nginx you can use this:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this for PHP 7.4:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml
```

And for PHP 8.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-xml
```

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
yum search php-xml
```

Then, choose one to yum install

```
yum install php71-php-xml.x86_64
```

Centos7 php7

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple php in your Ubuntu 22.x, you need to provide specific php version.

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-xml (or)
sudo apt-get install php8.2-xml
```

or you can check first whether the package available

```
apt search php8.2-xml
```